# How to fix the appearance of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anybody help me fix this problem?

I write code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer;
    tp = 500;
    cnav = ".categories";
    fsb = "li.submenu_f";
    ssb = "li.submenu_s";
    $(cnav).find("ul li:has(> ul)").addClass("submenu_f");
    $(cnav).find("ul li ul li:has(> ul)").attr("class", "submenu_s");
    $(fsb).hover(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(cnav).css("width", "561px");
        $(fsb).find("ul").show();
    }, function() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $(cnav).css("width", "303px");
            $(fsb).find("ul").hide();
        }, tp);
    });
    $(ssb).hover(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(cnav).css("width", "803px");
        $(ssb).find("ul").show();
    }, function() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $(cnav).css("width", "561px");
            $(ssb).find(ul).hide();
        }, tp);
    });
});
```

```css
.categories {
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 47px;
    top: 54px;
    width: 303px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.categories ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 274px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 215px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.categories ul li ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    left: 258px;
    width: 197px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categories">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Электроника</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Бытовая техника</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Компьютеры</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Товары для дома</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Товары для авто</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Сад и огород</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Строительство и ремонт</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="">Подарки и украшения</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Теле-видео-аудио техника</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Телефоны и связь</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="">Фото и видео</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">Плиты</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">Вытяжки</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">Холодильники</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">Духовые шкафы</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">Варочные поверхности</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">Посудомоечные машины</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">Стиральные машины</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">Аксессуары</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Портативная электроника</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Прочая электроника</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Элементы питания</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Парфюмерия и косметика</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Товары для детей</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="">Доп. меню</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="">link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">link 2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="">hover link 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="title">test</li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">test link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">test link 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Товары для спорта и отдыха</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Товары для животных</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Одежда и обувь</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Бытовая химия</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Фермерские товары</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

OR: http://jsfiddle.net/wagwandude/6dWCg/18/

When hover on li.submenu_f we see ul li ul, when hover on li.submenu_s we see ul li ul li ul. It works, but when I add to 1 more submenu - I find problem.
Menu superimposed on each other.. I can't fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, `$(fsb)` gets everything with class `.submenu_f`, so instead of `$(fsb).find("ul").show()` and `$(fsb).find("ul").hide()`, replace `$(fsb)` with `$(this)`, which only gets the `li` that is hovered over.

Then, you will want the `ul li ul` from one `li` to hide when you hover over another `li`, so you should just hide all `ul li ul` on each hover:

```
$(fsb).hover(function(){
    $(fsb).find("ul").hide();
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(cnav).css("width", "561px");
    $(this).find("ul").show();
}, function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(cnav).css("width", "303px");
        $(this).find("ul").hide();
    }, tp);
});  

$(ssb).hover(function(){
    $(ssb).find("ul").hide();
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(cnav).css("width", "803px");
    $(this).find("ul").show();
}, function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(cnav).css("width", "561px");
        $(this).find("ul").hide();
    }, tp);
});
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4t1u0a2a/2/